# Error in building code in opencv

Tags: opencv

I am using visual studio 2008. I configured OpenCV with Visual studio. But i am getting the following error.

```
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>fatal error RC1109: error creating .\Debug\OPEN_CV_TEST.exe.embed.manifest.res
1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\rc.exe'.
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\GARGI\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\OPEN_CV_TEST\OPEN_CV_TEST\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>OPEN_CV_TEST - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's related to OpenCV ?

The `RC1109` error happens sometimes if Visual Studio try to create a file in a "read only" folder. I would recommend digging that way.